# Issues Vectorizing Stroke

Tags: vector, sketch-app, stroke

I'm trying to create an icon that I build using the stroke tool. However, when I go to vectorize the stroke, some weird stuff starts happening.

Original, correct:
[image: Original, correct]

Stroke vectorized, not what I want: 
[image: Stroke vectorized, not what I want]

Anyone have any ideas what might be the culprit for this? Here's a view of what Sketch is doing with the groups:

[image: Groups]

Comment: What do you mean 'vectorized' in this context? If you are using Sketch, the stroke *is* a vector.

Comment: I can see how that is confusing. "Vectorize Stroke" under ```Layer > Paths > Vectorize Stroke``` is the command for changing a stroke to a shape object.

Comment: Sounds like I need to start using Sketch! That is a very odd wording they are using compared to illustrator!

Answer (score 2):

Friend at work helped me out, happily:

Before trying to vectorize the stroken I needed to use `Layer > Paths > Flatten` on the shape. Worked like a charm :)